# Python: Downloading Zip files is not working once in a for-loop

Tags: python, python-requests, zip

I am doing a simple download and write of zip files. I used a single url first and everything downloaded and saved perfect. Once I put the code in a for-loop it only writes an empty zip file. What is happening?

Thank You!

```
 import requests
 def download_file(url): 
     print (url)
     local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
     r = requests.get(url)
     output = open(TempDir + '\\' + local_filename, 'wb')
     output.write(r.content)
     print (TempDir + '\\' + local_filename)
     output.close()

 for url in urllist:
     download_file(url)
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, probably something wrong with your `urllist`, or the contents you're trying to download.

Comment: That is helpful to know. I will double check the list.

Comment: yes, it was whitespaces in my list, thanks